How to get redirected url in Python?
I have a list of url to songs' tiktok page url in the form of f'https://www.tiktok.com/music/-{songid}'. If I enter it in my browser, I'll be redirected to a page with a longer url, which is what I want to get.
I was trying methods in other posts using requests and urllib.request, but neither works. What's happening? How could I get the redirected url in this case? Thank you!
For example, if I enter https://www.tiktok.com/music/-7224086788926638082 it in my browser, I'll be redirected to https://www.tiktok.com/music/UNFORGIVEN-feat-Nile-Rodgers-7224086788926638082, which is what I want to get. However, the following codes all return the original url, instead of the redirected one:
import requests
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/music/-7224086788926638082'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)

import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/music/-7224086788926638082'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(r.geturl())

import requests
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/music/-7224086788926638082'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.head(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
print(response.url)


Does this answer your question? Python follow redirects and then download the page?

Sadly nope, requests.head doesn't work neither

Maybe because the server only redirects for particular user agents? Have you tried sending a request in python exactly as your browser sends it? Have you checked if the redirect happens in javascript?

Yes I have, but it doesn't work neither
